# iReport (5.1.0) for Mac OSX 10.8.4 , The document has no pages Error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a problem with `iReport (5.1.0)` for `Mac OSX 10.8.4:`
When I create my report and preview I always receive an error message:

```
The document has no pages.
```

The connector used is `mysql` and `datsources` works.

Comment: It means your datasource returned no data. Are you sure your query returns data?

Comment: yes , i'm sure The query return data.

Comment: Can you post the related `jrxml` in your problem?